# What is the Fourier transform of $1/f(x)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Given $F(t) = \mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$, how can one express $\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\right\}$ in terms of $F(t)$?

**EDIT:** To be more concrete, I want to compute $\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}\right\}$.  So far I have $\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}\right\} = \mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\right\}\star\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}\right\}$, where $\star$ denotes convolution.  The point of this computation is to use the resulting expression in a numerical method (spectral Galerkin), so $f$ and $g$ do not have a specific analytical form.

Comment: If you have a more concrete computation to perform it is better you post it. The Fourier transform doesn't behave nicely with respect to multiplication.

Comment: @Alamos, see edit.  Unfortunately I can't get more concrete than that.

Comment: Such questions get asked once in a while... unfortunately, nonlinear transforms like changing $f$ to $1/f$ are completely intractable on the Fourier side. There is no useful answer.